# Linux mint - panel settings automatically reset after cloning ssd

Tags: linux-mint, settings, panel

I have cloned a linux mint 19.2 ssd, and now when I open the panel settings, I can't save any change and any change immediately resets on the ui, too.

## Installation details

(GPT disk)

- efi partition
- swap partition
- /home
- /

The source disk was a 2,5" sata ssd, the target disk is an nvme ssd. I cloned the disk using dd with `conv=noerror,sync` options. According to dd's output, everything was copied successfully. Grub needed to be reinstalled before I could boot the disk.

## Error messages

When I start `cinnamon-settings panel` (with or without sudo) from the terminal, I get two of this error message:

```
(cinnamon-settings.py:7377): dconf-WARNING **: 17:32:56.237: failed to commit changes to dconf:
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code17:
Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For those that stumble upon this question later, I managed to solve it: It seems that the dconf database that stored the settings has been corrupted. To reset it, I had to delete the `~/.local/dconf/user` file. The system automatically generated a new database file with the default values in it, which was now editable.

Found the file's location [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1290596#p1290596).

***Warning: I don't know what other settings this file stores. Deleting it resets everything else it stores, of course.***